# Android project (Java/C++) std::runtime_error not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to migrate one project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

After importing the project, fixe the errors within Gradle, I must follow this post (after this error message : *[..] Please use the experimental plugin*)
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

I'm stuck on a point :

In Jni folder, "std::runtime_error" is not found example :

[image]

Whereas other methods of std are availables,

My Application.mk :

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-22 
APP_STL := gnustl_shared 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

My Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := NativeModule
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRAIRIES += libstlport
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += bionic
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fexceptions -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 -frtti
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
                    swigITrame_wrap.cpp \
                    [......]
                    Thread.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Someone he had this problem ?

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdexcept>` in your file?

Comment: Yes  I try, but in cpp file I've this : "unused import statement" after include <stdexcept> ... it's strange, same for #include <exception>

Comment: Try using `APP_STL := gnustl_static`?

Comment: By the way, you have a typo in `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`, extra `I`.

Comment: nothing changes with *gnustl_static*

Comment: thank you for a typo, but nothing changes :-(

Comment: I think you want to remove "LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRAIRIES += libstlport
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport". Specifying the APP_STL should take care of the STL for you.

Comment: How are you building your code? Are you using ndk-build or the experimental NDK/Gradle integration?

Comment: experimental NDK/Gradle integration :)